# Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Load not there

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using EF and I have the following code in which I am trying to get rows from a view called interface5toSSHIP. The SQL Explorer reveals that the database view has one row right now. The following query doesn't seem to return it. What am I doing wrong?

```
IEnumerable<interface5toSSHIP> i5;
            using (RREM_GilbaneEntities3 entities3 = new RREM_GilbaneEntities3())
            {
                i5 = from i in entities3.interface5toSSHIP
                select i;
            }
```

Then I get the title error when I attempt to DataBind it:

```
grdvwInterface5ReadyToSend.DataSource = i5;
            grdvwInterface5ReadyToSend.AllowPaging = true;
            grdvwInterface5ReadyToSend.AllowSorting = true;
            grdvwInterface5ReadyToSend.DataBind();
```

The problem is I can't find how to do the Load. I looked up an example like this:

```
IntranetModelContainer db = new IntranetModelContainer();
      db.Entities.OfType<Employee>().Load();
      return db.Entities.Local.OfType<Employee>();
```

I added a reference to System.Data.Entity and I can't find a .Entities off my entities3 or a LOad method. How do I do this?

Comment: The query is working. I just need to know how to DataBind to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it by calling the ToList() method on it.

Comment: Be careful `ToList()` will all data without pagination. it is better to perform pagination at database. this approach reduce network bandwidth and memory consumption at application side

Answer (score 0):

ToList() can be too slow, because it will try to get all properties (get{}) and resolve another objects related to it. A fast way can be:

```
yourLinq.AsQueryable()
```

Comment: I down voted this. The intention is good but the understanding of the problem was missed. .AsQueryable() in no way solves the problem at hand and when binding to a web control from a DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery or DbRawSqlQuery it will always produce the same error. While I agree .ToList() can be slow and inefficient it is probably the best solution to this question. If your EF Object contains lots of object relations the best solution would be to build a detached object first that only includes the properties you need so not all related object properties are executed when calling .ToList()